# Transform a list in another with stream map java 8

Tags: java

I want to create a list of ErroDto based on a list of FieldError using stream and another options from java 8. I had this with forEach but I want with stream and map:

```
fieldErrors.stream()
                   .forEach(e -> errosDto.add(new ErroDto(e.getField(), e.getDefaultMessage())));
```

I try like this below but I think its wrong because I'm modifying the second list inside the map:

```
fieldErrors.stream()
               .map(e -> errosDto.add(new ErroDto(e.getField(), e.getDefaultMessage())));
```

Then I want to map and collect as a list.

Comment: `...stream().map( e -> new ErroDto(...)).collect(toList())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` should only transform each `FieldError` instance to an `ErroDto` instance.

Use `collect` to collect all the `ErroDto` instances into a `List`:

```
List<ErroDto> errosDto =
    fieldErrors.stream()
               .map(e -> new ErroDto(e.getField(), e.getDefaultMessage()))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The lambda expression that you pass to the `map()` method takes the input object and returns the output object. You should not add it to the list inside the `map()` method itself. Collect the stream that comes out of `map()` into a `List<ErroDto>`:

```
List<ErroDto> errosDto = fieldErrors.stream()
    .map(e -> new ErroDto(e.getField(), e.getDefaultMessage()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```